# I want to show notification when app killed from recent apps

Tags: android, lifecycle

when user swipe my app from recent apps, how can we show notification, any help appreciated.

Comment: I am not getting clue, whenever I open stackoverflow.com , I always get a new question

Comment: sorry I didn't get you @lucifer

Answer (score 0):

when you open app from overview button, first it will call onStart() and second it will call onResume() method.

Answer (score 0):

As per developer site when any activity is launched it will call onCreate() method for you reference kindly g to the [this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html)

Answer (score 0):

after some R&D I got the solution, we can use `onTaskRemove(Intent intent)`method of service. it will hit when we swipe our app from overview screen

Comment: which class has his method?

Comment: in Service class we have onTaskRemoved(Intent intent) method

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Override
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    Intent i= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ServiceName.class);
    stopService(i);
}
```